# Symbol validation error because containing of space

Tags: javascript, validation, symbols

I was trying to validate a string using javascript, I was trying to validate it in a way it couldn't contain any symbol, my code works, but when user inputs any space it will cause an error.

I tried to erase the string but it didn't work.
Here's what I have tried:

```
function validateSymbol(word)
{
    var newword=word.split(' ').join('');

    for(var i = 0; i < newword.length; i++)
    {
        if(word.charCodeAt(i) < 48 ||
           newword.charCodeAt(i) > 57 &&
           newword.charCodeAt(i) < 65 ||
           newword.charCodeAt(i) > 90 &&
           newword.charCodeAt(i) < 97 ||
           newword.charCodeAt(i) > 122)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you please give the error message

Comment: Hi Kumar! i just edited the code, it always return false when there's space inside word. thanks for caring :)

Comment: can you make a fiddle?? with ur sample input.. what is the value of "word" when calling this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you haven't replaced `word` with `newword` in first `if` condition

```
function validateSymbol(word)
{
    var newword=word.split(' ').join('');

    for(var i = 0; i < newword.length; i++)
    {
        if(newword.charCodeAt(i) < 48 ||
           newword.charCodeAt(i) > 57 &&
           newword.charCodeAt(i) < 65 ||
           newword.charCodeAt(i) > 90 &&
           newword.charCodeAt(i) < 97 ||
           newword.charCodeAt(i) > 122)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @HannanHossain Have you tried the code? It is clear that my suggestion makes sense.

Comment: of course I have tried that code. I tell my opinion after trying that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hannnan/qBAuS/
@vooD have a look. I didn't find any problem as you described. I don't know how his problem solved.

Comment: @HannanHossain, there is misunderstanding. 'Error' in this context means that function returns ```false``` when ```word``` param contains space character. Question was "how to fix the function so it returns ```true``` when ```word``` contains space character?"

Comment: @vooD I know and that's clear. But have you seen my fiddle. there is no checking with word variable within loop. It's only matter of newword variable. But it doesn't contain any space after executing this 
var newword=word.split(' ').join('');
I don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @vooD there is no offence. But I need to know what is the point.. It's not clear enough. How can his problem solved.. May be question owner knows it well.. :D

Comment: both are you are great!! thanks for help and caring :D
its wrong because i put wrong variable inside 1st condition

Comment: @vooD I am really sorry for arguing with you. I haven't seen and can't imagine that he can made such silly mistake. He used word variable in first condition.